# Tumblr Audio Player not loading with Infinite Scroll

Tags: tumblr, audio-player

I implemented infinite scroll along with masonry on this tumblr: [check revision for link]

The audio player does not appear in posts loaded through infinite scroll, instead it displays the text "[Flash 9 is required to listen to audio.]"

The Inspire Well tumblr theme (I can't post another hyperlink but you can easily google it) seems to have solved this problem through this code:

```
if(InspireWell.infiniteScrolling && InspireWell.indexPage){
  $masonedColumn.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : 'ul.page_nav',  // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : 'ul.page_nav li.page_next a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.post',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loadingImg : '',
    donetext  : 'No more pages to load.',
    errorCallback: function() { 
      // fade out the error message after 2 seconds
      //$('#infscr-loading').animate({opacity: .8},2000).fadeOut('normal');   
    }
  },
  // call masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) { 

    $(newElements).css({ visibility: 'hidden' });

    $(newElements).each(function() {
      if($(this).hasClass("audio")){
        var audioID = $(this).attr("id");
        var $audioPost = $(this);
        $audioPost.find(".player span").css({ visibility: 'hidden' });

        var script=document.createElement('script');
        script.type='text/javascript';
        script.src="http://assets.tumblr.com/javascript/tumblelog.js?16";

        $("body").append(script);

        $.ajax({
        url: "http://thetestinggrounds.tumblr.com/api/read/json?id=" + audioID,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          timeout: 5000,
          success: function(data){
            $audioPost.find(".player span").css({ visibility: 'visible' });
            $audioPost.find("span:first").append('<script type="text/javascript">replaceIfFlash(9,"audio_player_' + audioID + '",\'\x3cdiv class=\x22audio_player\x22\x3e' + data.posts[0]['audio-player'] +'\x3c/div\x3e\')</script>');
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

I tried to adapt this for my tumblr (with placeholder text to see if it was finding the correct element):

```
 $(window).load(function(){
   $('#allposts').masonry({
     singleMode: true,
     itemSelector: '.box' 
   });
   $('#allposts').infinitescroll({
     navSelector : "div.navigation",
     nextSelector : "div.navigation a:first",
     itemSelector : ".box",
     debug : true
   },
     function( newElements ) {
       $(this).masonry({ appendedContent: $( newElements ) });
       $(newElements).each(function(){
         if($(this).hasClass("audio")){
           var audioID = $(this).attr("id");
       var $audioPost = $(this);
       $audioPost.find(".audio span");
           var script=document.createElement('script');
           script.type='text/javascript';
           script.src="http://assets.tumblr.com/javascript/tumblelog.js?16";
           $("body").append(script);
       $.ajax({
         url: "http://fuckyeahempathy.tumblr.com/api/read/json?id=" + audioID,
     dataType: "jsonp",
     timeout: 5000,
     success: function(data){
       $audioPost.find(".audio span");
       $audioPost.find("span:first").append("<p>audio player not working</p>");
         }
       });
         }
       });
     }
   ); 
});
```

But there is no sign of the text.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution I came up with when I needed to implement the same functionality in the template I was creating.

In your HTML, include your AudioPlayer Tumblr tag between comments. This is to prevent loaded scripts from being called. Also add a class "unloaded" to keep track whether or not we've loaded the audio player for this post or not.

```
...
{block:AudioPlayer}
    <div class="audio-player unloaded">
        <!--{AudioPlayerBlack}-->
    </div>
{/block:AudioPlayer}
...
```

If you look at the commented code after the page is loaded, you will notice an embed tag being passed to one of the Tumblr javascript functions. Since we commented it, it will not execute. Instead we will want to extract this string and replace the div contents with it.

Create a javascript function which will do this. This can be done with regular javascript, but to save time I will do it with jQuery since this is how I did it for my template:

```
function loadAudioPosts() {
    // For each div with classes "audio-player" and "unloaded"
    $(".audio-player.unloaded").each(function() {

        // Extract the <embed> element from the commented {AudioPlayer...} tag.
        var new_html = $(this).html().substring(
            $(this).html().indexOf("<e"),    // Start at "<e", for "<embed ..."
            $(this).html().indexOf("d>")+2   // End at "d>", for "...</embed>"
        );

        // Replace the commented HTML with our new HTML
        $(this).html(new_html);

        // Remove the "unloaded" class, to avoid reprocessing
        $(this).removeClass("unloaded");
    });
}
```

Call `loadAudioPosts()` once on page load, then every time your infinite scrolling loads additional posts.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div class="audio" id="{postID}">{AudioPlayerBlack}</div>
```

css

```
.audio {
        height:30px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
.audio span {
        display:none;
    }
```

java

```
setTimeout(function() {
                        $wall.masonry({ appendedContent: $(newElements) });
                        /* repair audio players*/
                        $('.audio').each(function(){
                            var audioID = $(this).attr("id");
                            var $audioPost = $(this);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://yoolk.tumblr.com/api/read/json?id=' + audioID,
                                dataType: 'jsonp',
                                timeout: 50000,
                                success: function(data){
                                    $audioPost.append('\x3cdiv style=\x22background-color:white;height:30px\x22 class=\x22audio_player\x22\x3e' + data.posts[0]['audio-player'] +'\x3c/div\x3e');
                                }
                            });
                        });


                    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Yoolk, sorry if I'm being daft but would you care to explain your answer a little further? How might one go about fixing this problem?