# Javascript breaking audio players

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I know about [this issue in tumblr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165501/tumblr-audio-video-players-masonry-with-infinite-scroll), the code gets stripped out and the audio players are broken.

I'm using flexslider.js now but the problem is pretty much the same. I fixed it with this

```
    setTimeout(function() {                        
                $('.audio').each(function(){
                    var audioID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                    var $audioPost = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/api/read/json?id=' + audioID,
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        timeout: 50000,
                        success: function(data){
                            if ($audioPost.html().indexOf("is required to") != -1) {
                            $audioPost.append('<div style=\"background-color:black;">' + data.posts[0]['audio-player'] +'</div>');
                                }
                            }
                    });
                });
            }, 2000);
```

You need to resize your browser window to see this because I started coding from the mobile version, anyway...it looks ok on permalink pages http://tmbeta.tumblr.com/post/21264072020 but it doesn't when the photosets (which use flexslider) and the player are on the same page http://tmbeta.tumblr.com/

See how the player is added to the bottom of the post? I want it to appear where it says [Flash 9 is required to listen to audio.] instead. I know it's basically what .append does but I'm not familiar enough with jquery so I'm really struggling to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your HTML, the result is not surprising: you are scoping  the `append()` to the element with the class `audio`, and that is the `<article>`. jQuery appends your new `div` to the end of that scope – which is the bottom of the article. You need to change the scope of your element insertion, either by

1. Iterating over elements of class `audio-player` instead of `audio`, i.e.

   ```
   $('.audio-player').each(function(){ … }
   ```

   As this changes the scope of `this`, you will also have to adjust the line retrieving the post ID to look up the element hierarchy, i.e.

   ```
   var audioID = $(this).parents('.audio').attr('id');
   ```

   or by
2. Scoping your element insertion to the player element proper, i.e.

   ```
   $audioPost.find('.audio-player').append('<div style=\"background-color:black;">' + data.posts[0]['audio-player'] +'</div>');
   ```

   If you’d rather replace the `span` inside that element instead of appending to it, so your player replaces the Flash warning, do

   ```
   $audioPost.find('#audio_player_'+audioID).replaceWith('<div style=\"background-color:black;">' + data.posts[0]['audio-player'] +'</div>');
   ```

   instead.

*Answer edited after some trial and error on-site testing via chat; please ignore the comment thread.*

Comment: Thanks! Tried that but now it says "undefined".

Comment: @Barbara: you will have to adjust the scope of your `audioID` – `this` is not the *audio* element anymore, but the *audio-player* element. Try changing line 3 to `var audioID = $(this).parent().attr("id");`.

Comment: Done. Must be something else too, it still says undefined.

Comment: @Barbara: what exactly is undefined? Please post your full error message, or even better: open the console (depending on your browser, you’ll need Firebug or can use the WebKit Inspector) and post your full error log…

Comment: Thanks for the help! Here where the player should be (http://i.imgur.com/yVYAh.png). The log http://pastebin.com/TAehgX4n and the code of lines 259 and 312 http://pastebin.com/JNp7tL3r

Comment: @Barbara: ah, I see – you are using V1 of the Tumblr API; that specific JSONP implementation strays rather far from [what is conventionally thought of as JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) by [setting a variable called `tumblr_api_read` to the returned data](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1#api_read). Which means you get “undefined” because, indeed, your `data` **is** undefined – try replacing it with `tumblr_api_read` and let me know the result.

Comment: Like this? I updated the code both here and on the page, you can see by yourself but looks like the player has completely disappeared.

Comment: Let’s close the comment thread – your original question has been answered (the re-scoped iteration places the player in the right spot, or would, if it retrieved the player). The new issue cropping up is one of the Tumblr API. It doesn’t belong in the question, though I’m quite willing to [discuss it in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10859/discussion-between-kopischke-and-barbara).