# Change Tumblr audio player color with Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, tumblr

I'm forced to load the tumblr audio player in my theme via JavaScript because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421855/javascript-breaking-audio-players). The loading happens as follows:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {                        
        $('.audio-player').each(function(){
            var audioID = $(this).parents(".audio").attr("id");
            var $audioPost = $(this);
            var color = "000000"; //new color
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/read/json?id=' + audioID,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                timeout: 50000,
                success: function(data){
                    if ($audioPost.html().indexOf("is required to") != -1) {
                        $audioPost.find('#audio_player_'+audioID).replaceWith('<div style=\"background-color:white;">' + data.posts[0]['audio-player'].replace("color=FFFFFF", "color=" + color) +'</div>'); //replace color here
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

In spite of using the {AudioPlayerBlack} tag, the code-inserted audio player is white, so I want to change that. I added two lines (commented in the code) and it’s sort of working: the player becomes black but all the controls are invisible. Instead of the expected

[image: regular black player]

I get this

[image: JavaScript loaded black player]

You can inspect the live example here: http://tmbeta.tumblr.com/ (btw, testing for mobiles so you need to resize your window to make it less than 480px wide). This is the [tumblr api for audio posts](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#audio-posts), just in case.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `background-color:white` style from your `div`?

Comment: @kopischke Hey! You're my SO hero these days :) It does nothing, the bg is the the area around the player. I removed the code and changed it to black so you can see what I'm referring to. http://i.imgur.com/SDLWq.png

Comment: oh right, I understand – it’s meant to be black… humph. Could you link to live code (same as last question)?

Comment: @kopischke Yep, default is white I want to change it to black so I grabbed the code from another theme and it's not working. Sure! the js is here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13823768/masonry/js/script.js and the live page here http://tmbeta.tumblr.com/

Comment: change `.replace("color=FFFFFF", "color=" + color)` to `.replace("audio_player.swf", "audio_player_black.swf")`.

Comment: @kopischke Done. No change. edit: no wait, the files are out of synch. Just a sec.

Comment: Problem gone. I’m adding this as an answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color scheme  of the Tumblr audio players is not governed by the color code passed in the request URL, as you assume – it is part of the `swf` (Flash) file itself. To get the black player, you need to request `audio_player_black.swf` instead of the default (white) `audio_player.swf`. In your code, change the innermost code line to

```
$audioPost.find('#audio_player_'+audioID).replaceWith('<div style=\"background-color:white;">' + data.posts[0]['audio-player'].replace("audio_player.swf", "audio_player_black.swf") +'</div>');
```

and you should be good to go. You can also get rid of the `color` definition, of course :).

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this is appropriate but if anyone's trying to simply change the background color of a standard tumblr audio player i have found this simple code to work.

(Haven't checked it everywhere, adding the color instead of replacing might be bad code but it seems to function fine?)

```
$('iframe.tumblr_audio_player').each(function(){
    var audio = $(this).attr('src')
    $(this).attr('src', audio + '&color=e84d37'); // replace w/ hex of whatever color
});
```