# Tumblr audio/video players not working when you add infinite scrolling code

Tags: tumblr, infinite-scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tumblr audio/video players + Masonry with infinite scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165501/tumblr-audio-video-players-masonry-with-infinite-scroll)

I'm using not infinite scrolling [tumblr theme called](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/6177) . So I search and found this [manual](http://tumblring.net/making-your-tumblr-an-endless-scrolling-page/).

I followed the instruction until method 3. Everything works except for the video and audio players, they won't load on the second page and so on, and display this message instead “Flash 9 is required to listen to audio.”. I've research everywhere and even message the one who made the theme and the website I gave above but no reply. So now I am trying this website. I'm new at this and definitely not a programmer. But detailed instructions I can follow.

Hope someone can help me. I really want my tumblr to have endless scrolling, so I can add steampad as a background music so all my music post will play.

Although I can add steampad without infinite scrolling it would not work out because when you turn the page the player will refresh and music will start all over again.

But at the same time I also want my videos and audio to work when people browse my tumblr. They can stop the steampad anytime anyways.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please show us the link to your blog. Is steampad player beginning to play immediately after the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165501/tumblr-audio-video-players-masonry-with-infinite-scroll)(do not pay attention to Masonry) will help you. I think the recommendations contained in this question should help.

You will need to add a script and edit html template of your theme on [customize page](http://www.tumblr.com/customize).