# tumblr audio + Masonry with infinite scroll- other solutions posted have confused me

Tags: javascript, tumblr, jquery-masonry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tumblr audio/video players + Masonry with infinite scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165501/tumblr-audio-video-players-masonry-with-infinite-scroll)

[This is what I am working on. a tumblr blog theme](http://fabric-theme.tumblr.com/) and I am having an issue similar to this

> All is fine except with audio players. They won't load on the second page and display this message instead [Flash 9 is required to listen to audio.].

```
      <script type="text/javascript" >
     $(function(){

       var $container = $('#blog');

       $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
         $container.masonry({
           itemSelector: '.post',
                            columnWidth: 275,
                    gutterWidth: 10,
                        isAnimated: true,
                        animationOptions: {
                            duration: 750,
                            easing: 'linear',
                            queue: false,
                        } 
         });
       });

       $container.infinitescroll({
         navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation
         nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
         itemSelector : '.post',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
         loading: {
             finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
             img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
           }
         },
         // trigger Masonry as a callback
         function( newElements ) {
           // hide new items while they are loading
           var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
           // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
           $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
             // show elems now they're ready
             $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
             $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
           });
         }
       );
     });
  </script>
```

[Other solutions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165501/tumblr-audio-video-players-masonry-with-infinite-scroll) say that I need to use the audio repair in the callback function, anywhere I try to implement this code in the original script I have above breaks the masonry code and messes up the grid layout. So I am asking you if you can help me, I am using the {PostID}
 where the audio player is 
`<div class="audio" id={PostID}>{AudioPlayerWhite}</div>`

like so

```
         <div class="post audio">
        {block:AlbumArt}
        <img src="{AlbumArtURL}" width="100%" />
        {/block:AlbumArt}
        <div class="audio" id={PostID}>{AudioPlayerWhite}</div>
        {block:IfHideCaption}{block:Caption}
        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
        {/block:Caption}{/block:IfHideCaption}
        <br />
        <div class="tmbl-ico">
           <div class="my-like" data-reblog="{ReblogURL}" data-id="{PostID}" title="Like"></div>
           <div class="my-reblog"><a href="{ReblogURL}"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/m3fp1tf/G3Wm7bksh/trans.png" /></a></div>
           <div class="my-plink"><a href="{Permalink}"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/m3fp1tf/G3Wm7bksh/trans.png" /></a></div>
        </div>
```

So how do I put this (the code below from other solution) into mine without it breaking? I also would like to know if the code from the other solution needs variables changed to my own and which ones that might be, I am pretty new at this.

Comment: So how do I put their fix in my code in the simplest way of asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165501/tumblr-audio-video-players-masonry-with-infinite-scroll

Comment: I put the audio repair part just after the `$newElems.imagesLoaded(...);` block. But note that you set the **container** of the audio player to have the `audio` class as well, which may be breaking the layout. Try changing the class of the audio player like this:  `<div class="audioPlay" id={PostID}>{AudioPlayerWhite}</div>`, and replace the class name in the audio repair code as well.