# Infinite Scroll & Tumblr Video Call Back

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, tumblr, infinite-scroll

— I'm having some problems getting Tumblr video posts to load after firing infinite scroll. 
Any one experienced this? I'm not using Masonary BTW.

– Here's what I have in the code:

```
        {block:Video}
            <div class="float four">
                <div class="video" id={PostID}>
                    {Video-500}
                </div>
            </div>
        {/block:Video}
```

...and:

```
        $(function() {
            $('#wrapper').infinitescroll({
                navSelector         : '.pagination',
                nextSelector        : '.pagination a.right',
                itemSelector        : '#wrapper > .index',
                    loading: {
                    img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/9snku1k/tIdlymgha/holder.png',
                    speed: 'slow',
                    msgText: '<div class="float clr_one inner">Loading...</div>',
                    finishedMsg: '<div class="float clr_one inner">The Beginning.</div>'
                    },
                extraScrollPx       : 0,
                bufferPx            : 250,
                animate             : true
            });
        });
```

— which fires back the following, with the iFrame stripped:

```
<div class=​"video" id=​"00000000000">​​
    <div id=​"tumblr_video_container_00000000000" class=​"tumblr_video_container" style=​"width:​500px;​height:​500px;​">
        /* Missing iFrame */
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a whole bunch of the callback functions I've found already posted and discussed, but these have all been for masonary ... it's doing my head in :)

```
                },

                function (newElements) {

                    ...     

                })
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165501/tumblr-audio-video-players-masonry-with-infinite-scroll?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks @Ally – I did try those but with no success. Thanks for pointing. Appriciated.