# How do I call a javascript function after AJAX loads content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flash, tumblr

I'm using some code for infinite scrolling on a Tumblr blog using AJAX, and it works very well except for when it comes to loading certain Flash content. The code for the infinite scroll is [here](http://static.tumblr.com/5huhcpw/HuQmfn8mh/infinitescroll.js).

I have a partial solution to the problem of Flash content using some [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897344/1119079) suggested by [Daniel K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1250319/daniel-k), a user on this site. I have implemented the code for calling the function on page load, however I cannot figure out how to call the function after the AJAX loads content for the infinite scroll.

I have several themes for Tumblr and a number of people have asked me to implement infinite scroll. I have been reluctant to add it because of the Flash problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You've linked to a wall of obfuscated-looking code.  Can you perhaps format it for the question?  Trim it down to the relevant part(s)?  Etc.  From the description itself, it sounds like all you need to do is call a function in the response handler for the AJAX request.

Comment: I thought that would be what was required, I'm just stumped as to where that is. At any rate, I have uploaded a [formatted version](http://static.tumblr.com/5huhcpw/6U9mfqyfq/infinitescroll.js) of the code that should make it a bit easier to read through.

Comment: You might want to clarify that you're using **Auto Pager** for your endless scrolling and not the Infinite Scroll project. I could've easily told you where to put the AJAX callback function if it was Infinite Scroll. I don't have much experience with Auto Pager so I'll need to look at the code before it was obfuscated (i.e. minified to replace all the functions and variable names with alphabetical letters to reduce length.) Just showing me the functions separated isn't really helping because I can't look at it and quickly know which function is which. I'll go look for Auto Pager and come back.

Comment: I used Aptana to format the source code and it looks like you'll need to add something to either the `addNextPage` function, where the elements are being appended, or in `sendRequest` where the request is actually being made but `sendRequest` is almost impossible to understand since everything is just letters.

Answer (score 0):

The code in this answer can probably be fixed up a bit, but it should work for you in the time being. Just make sure to place it within your infinite scroll callback.

[Tumblr Audio & Video + Infinite Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404807/tumblr-audio-video-infinite-scroll/12481862#12481862)